# Unable to load embedded dependencies from the GAC

Tags: dll, ilmerge, fody, fody-costura

I made an HttpModule that I'm adding to the GAC and then registering it in my web.config. I used [Fody Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to embed dependencies. The output in my bin folder consists of only one dll, one .config and one .pdb (Because all the dependencies are merged into that file.) My problem is that whenever I load the module from the GAC, it is unable to find the embeded dependencies. I have the following observations:

- Whenever my module is loaded from the /bin folder, everything works ok. I register the module as follows:

```html
<modules>
  <add name="MyModule" type="MyNamespace.MyModule.Module, MyNamespace.MyModule"/>
</modules>
```

- When I load my module from the GAC, my module is unable to load dependencies. I get the following message:

  Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My module is loaded as follows:

```html
<modules>
  <add name="MyModule" type="MyNamespace.MyModule.Module, MyNamespace.MyModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7d22d90bda7ffgab, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
</modules>
```

I'm thinking that my module does not know that the dependencies are within itself. Is there any way I can tell my module to load the dependencies from the merged dll? Or anyone that can point me in the right direction? I'm a little bit lost here. Thanks!

Comment: looks like you have dependency to Newtonsoft.Json in your project. Does it have 'Copy Local' attribute set?

Comment: Yes, all of my required dependencies have "Copy Local" = true

Comment: @JorgeZuverza Have I answered your question? Could you accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that problem is related to `Newtonsoft.Json` itself.

These issues say that there is a problem with the same strong name of different `Newtonsoft.Json` versions:

- [Newtonsoft.Json.dll release incompatible versions with same strong name #615](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/615)
- [Newtonsoft.Json.dll release incompatible versions with same strong name #1001](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1001)

So, if there is one version is already installed in GAC and you try to install another one, it won't be installed.

> Assemblies that have the same strong name should be identical.
>
> [Strong-Named Assemblies | MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies)

As the result, your application couldn't find required version of `Newtonsoft.Json` in GAC because it's not there.

If you could try to avoid using GAC, it should solve the problem.

Comment: I have no versions of Newtonsoft.Json installed in the GAC. I'm expecting this dependency to be embedded in my dll.  If I install Newtonsoft.Json in the GAC, Newtonsoft.Json does not fail. However, my next dependency (in this case OWIN) fails the same way Newtonsoft does. Therefore, I believe it is an issue with costura, or the system finding the embedded dependencies. Not with Newtonsoft itself.

Comment: @JorgeZuverza What is the exact name of OWIN library and what is its version?